# Connecting IBOutlets to UITableViewCell prototype

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode5

I am creating a UITable with custom UITableViewCell prototype. 
My cell contains UIImageViews, UILabels and UIButtons.

When I control and drag from my buttons to my class' interface it works just fine. However, it does not work with outlets.

When I create the IBOutlet in the .h file, I can only connect if I select the UITable not the cell and of course the result is a broken app.

Do you guys have any idea how to solve this? I do not want to use a custom class just for the cell. I really would like to stick with Storyboard and prototypes.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please provide examples

Comment: What's wrong about using a custom class?

Comment: Nothing wrong. I was wondering if I could do the same as I can do when I connect an Action (dragging and dropping)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using Labels with tag will get the job done but never a good practise ... the best way is to create a custom class of UITableViewCell.

ie, select

***New File>Cocoa Touch >Objective C Class***

and
Create it as a subclass of UITableViewCell
now you will get .h and .m files..

Next step is to create the view of the cell for this

select

***New File> User Interface > Empty***

and now create this with same name of your customcell class (lets say "CustomCell")

now you will have three files **CustomCell.h,CustomCell.m,CustomCell.xib**

now select the xib file and add UITableViewCell object on the xib and set its custom class as "CustomCell"

Look below pic
[image]

now after this you can drag any thing (UIImageView,UITextfield,UIButton) to the below view and give outlets onto the CustomClass  and manage the actions using delegate methods..

if you have imageView outlet as titleImage ..then you can access the same by creating the cell object in CellForRowAtIndex (TableView delgate method) to set image.

```
cell.titleImage=[UIImage ImageNamed:@"goo.png"];
```

now one more thing i have to say is that you have to implement an init method also in CustomCell.m to load the nib>>

it will look like the below code.

```
    -(id)initWithDelegate:(id)parent reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
    {
        
        if (self = [self initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier])
        {
            self=(CustomCell*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];
        }
        
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        self.backgroundView = NULL;
        self.selectedBackgroundView =NULL;
            
//If you want any delegate methods and if cell have delegate protocol defined
self.delegate=parent;
    
//return cell
    return self;
    }
```

Now it is better to have delegates if you are using buttons on your cell

so that in the button action method you can call delegate method (pass cell object) and implement the delegate in your ViewController with TableView

here is the example

[image]

now you can use your cell for UITableView to populate...and dont for get to set reuseIdentifier Value in CustomCell.xib (same as you set CustomClass)

lets set it namely ,hmm what else "customCell"

so while populating the tableView use

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *cellIdentifier=@"customCell";
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if(cell==nil)
         cell= [[CustomCell alloc] initWithDelegate:self reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
       
//set cell properties
   cell.titleImage=[UIImage ImageNamed:@"title.png"];

    
    
    return cell;
}
```

also dont forget to add delegate methods

give

```
ViewController:UIViewController<CustomCellDelegate>
```

on your  ViewController.h file of ViewController

and then implement its body in your  ViewController.m (implementation file)

as

```
  -(void)cellButtonPressed:(CustomCell*)cell
    {
NSIndexPath *indexPathOfPressedCell = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSLog(@"Pressed");
    }
```

This will look like a long method but it's quite useful and readable...

**-------NB----------:**

Also, return the CustomCell height
by implementing

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{}
```

it may occur....

Comment: Thanks for the thoroughly answer. cell.index = indexPath.row you mean inside the cellForRowAtIndex... right? If I use storyboard and prototype cell I can skip the init method or I do need to overwrite it?

Comment: @Camus no dude..
If you use this method you do not need to use a prototypecell on to your TableView (ie drag and drop on to TableView). Just change the cell type of table view as dynamic prototypes.
and about cell.index .. you are right ...
If you have any alignment issue just  return the CustomCell height
by implementing 

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{}

it may occur....

Comment: I got it. I tested using prototype cell and it works just fine. I prefer this because I do not need to create a XIB. Thanks

Comment: ok,while using the prototype cell your nib file path may change!!
but using xib is a good practise....you know ..coz if you want change any features or add any... you can easily edit on the xib than on the storyboard ..will make it more congested...but its your choice and is according to need...

Comment: Actually I just need to change the line where I write dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: @Raon

Answer (score 4):

You have to create a custom UITableViewCell class for the cell and then only cntrl + dragging to  create outlets make sense , other wise there is a even simpler way. Have tags like 99343 , 99345(to avoid overlaps) to your UIImageViews , UILabels etc and access them like

```
  UILabel *myLabelFromPrototypeCell = (UILabel*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:99343];
```

Comment: I am doing this way. However, I am storing them in properties so I can use them in others methods. I asked the question because I guess it is to messy setting all my views in the cell in the protocol tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath