# Dynamically create row in UITableView to show custom data

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have 2 simple classes:

```
Class1 {
    int i;
    NSString s;
}

Class2 {
    NSString name;
    NSString age;
}
```

In my UIViewController I have 2 NSMutableArray, each array holding multiple objects of Class1 & Class2.

I need to create a new section for each Array and number of rows in section should be equal to the number of objects on that array. 
Also in each cell I need to display the data of each object variables.

Please help!!!

Comment: "Please help!!!" is not a good start point. What have you tried before? Have you write some code? If so, can you show it to us in order to help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code...

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    return 2;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    switch (section) {
        case 0:
            return self.class1Array.count;


        case 1:
            return self.class2Array.count;
    }
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
     UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(cell==nil)
    {
       cell= [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    }
switch(indexPath.section)
{
    case 0:
    cell.textLabel.text=[self.class1Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] s];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=[self.class1Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] i];
    return cell;
    case 1:
    cell.textLabel.text=[self.class2Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=[self.class1Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] age];
    return cell;
}

}
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to create custom cells try to do like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19311807/connecting-iboutlets-to-uitableviewcell-prototype/19314715#19314715)

Comment: But what in case if i have to show both variable data in detailed text, and what in case if i have 5 data variables to be shown in detailed text. E.g my detailed text should be like

1. My Name\n
2. My Age\n
3. My Address\n
4. My Home Town\n

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if(tableview.section==0)
{
   cell.label.text= [aray1 object at index :indexpath.row]
} 

else if(tableview.section==1)
{
   cell.label.text= [aray object at index :indexpath.row]
}
```